# How do I use ALT codes on a Dell Windows 7 laptop with no numlock key or FN keypad?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, dell-vostro, alt-code

At work I'm using a Dell Vostro laptop running Windows 7 Enterprise and it does not have a <kbd>NumLock</kbd> key nor a numeric keypad accessible with <kbd>Fn</kbd>.

In this case, how do I enter an <kbd>Alt</kbd> code (holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and typing a number on the numpad)?

Before you ask, the on screen keyboard doesn't work.

Character Map is quite [horrible, and I'd rather avoid it](https://superuser.com/q/460244/79846).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wordpad/Word/Outlook etc. allow also to use  <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> combination. 
Enter ***hex*** code and immediately after press Alt-x (eg. <kbd>4</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> will produce `A`). 
Detailed instructions (with much more information) in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#In_Microsoft_Windows)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a numeric keyboard to input the desired code, you can use the build-in windows Character Map Utility:

1. Click "Start" menu button;
2. Select: Programs → Accessories → System Tools → Character Map;
3. A window should open with a grid displaying the characters:

   [image: Character Map]
4. Select the font you're using on your target application;

   <sup>Arial works very well across the board and presents all characters. There are exceptions  of course.</sup>
5. Scroll the chars grid to locate the desired character;
6. use the button "select" to select it to the copy area;

   [image: Character Map - Selected]
7. Copy the characters when you're done;
8. Past them on you desirable location.

Character Map Utility comes with lots of useful features, take a look at [this article](http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/accents/charmap.html) that explains all this with greater detail.

Comment: Character map is missing a bunch of characters and subranges. I [need something better](http://superuser.com/q/460244/79846).

Answer (score 3):

There is a subset of characters directly available if you enable [AltGr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altgr) which means changing your keyboard type to International. This changes your Right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key into a special kind of shift key, letting you type characters like « and » or letters like á and Þ.