# Replacement for horrible, horrible Character Map

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, unicode

Character Map is a horrible, horrible utility. What is a good free alternative?

Ideally, I hope to find a program that comes close to Mac OS X's Character Palette in terms of features & functionality. Specifically: I need a character name search that works, the ability to look at all codepoints (not just what is in one particular typeface) and a listing of all Unicode planes.

Comment: I've never found Character Map to be horrible.  I've actually appreciated the fact that you could search for a character by Unicode name...

Answer (score 7):

BabelMap is a free character map application for Windows that allows you to browse through the entire Unicode character repertoire, or search for a particular character by name or by code point.

It is freeware and comes as a portable executable - beat that!

http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html

Comment: The link seems to be down at the moment. Here's an alternative link to the portable version http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/babelmap-portable

Comment: WinCompose by Sam Hocevar (free and open-source) can also be used to enter special characters. For example, by default, to enter the symbol £ one can type AltGr then - (dash) then L.
https://github.com/samhocevar/wincompose

Answer (score 5):

Soft-Gems' Unicode Font Viewer ([Download Page](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/all-downloads)) and ergonis's "[PopChar](http://www.ergonis.com/downloads/dnld_popcharwin.html)" come pretty close to what you are looking for. I personally prefer the later, particularly due to the nicer UI. It's a shareware so try it out before jumping the gun (wallet).

Comment: PopChar looks good, but €30 ($36) is too much at this time. It will be the middle of next week before I can give either of these a shot.

Comment: I just tried Unicode Font Viewer, it's certainly better about displaying a plain than character map, but the UI is too unfriendly.