# Alt-Codes in tactile numpad

Tags: laptop, numpad, alt-code

I have a ASUS Zephyrus laptop and this model doesn't have a proper numpad, instead, its [trackpad](https://cnet1.cbsistatic.com/img/5gZ4ULuh-KHmN2cj_3PR_SIXGb0=/2017/06/23/8cd4d414-172a-43e9-9f6c-8f278bddd464/asus-rog-zephyrus-16.jpg) doubles has one.
That being said, I'm having troubles with inserting Unicode characters using Alt-Codes.

Pressing `Alt + Code Number` doesn't work correctly. It works if I'm pressing the numbers (all at the same time) and then Alt, but not the other way around (as it should be)

Is this normal for an integrated numpad, if not, how do I fix this issue?

Comment: Is it really that much of an issue if you simply press alt after the numbers instead of before?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work perfectly you have to be pressing all the numbers simultaneously (which isn't confortable and doesn't allow repeated digits codes) and since you press them before, those numbers will appear many times before the designated character does

Comment: Would the accepted answer here help you? https://superuser.com/questions/459309/how-do-i-use-alt-codes-on-a-dell-windows-7-laptop-with-no-numlock-key-or-fn-keyp?rq=1 A tad inconvenient but still better than not being able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution! I have a similar ASUS laptop with touchpad numpad and just randomly tried [an idea I got](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/702188/cant-do-alt-codes-on-asus-laptop/#:%7E:text=Hello!-,Tried%20ALT%20or%20ALT%2BFN,-.%20Yeah%20Numlock%20is) and it worked!.

For whatever reason **you need to be pressing the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key aswell**. So for example, instead of doing **<kbd>Alt</kbd> + `0167`** you have to do **<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + `0167`**.

Hope this helps as I have been facing this issue for some time and feel really happy now that I can use alt codes. Credit goes to the Matt714 on the forum linked above though!

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

On my Asus Zenbook, it can work in MS Word. You just have to hit spacebar (or enter) after the alt code.
alt+0151 (then no keys at all) spacebar.

In browsers and text editors it does not seem to work though.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the normal ALT + code entry method, you can also use Unicode entry to input characters (input the hex values, followed by <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>).  On Windows OS, any program that uses the Windows Rich Edit environment will natively accept this entry method, so this means you won't need to install anything additional and you should get this capability out-of-box with programs such as Word, Notepad, etc (on Windows 11, even `notepad.exe` supports this feature).  Personally, I would call `notepad.exe` through `run` and copy/paste it over from there if it's just the occasional use here and there, otherwise I'd look for additional automation if the use case calls for a higher frequency of use.

There are also other solutions, such as a registry key edit to enable a different form of hex inputs (this solution wouldn't work well with your issue, though, as it utilizes the numpad), or 3rd party / external applications designed for this purpose.  You can also look into using, e.g., [AHK](https://www.autohotkey.org) to create your own custom methods to input special characters.

PS: If you happen to have a Chromebook and have been wondering how to input unicode characters on there, it's a very similar process: input <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and type the hex value.